# geode oql order by a string and to_date

Tags: gemfire, geode

I have a region which contains transaction times input as strings in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff` and I'd like to be able to run an OQL query with results ordered by transaction time. Whether as a string or a date...

If I run the order by then the results are not coming back ordered.

`query --query="select distinct d.value FROM /deal.entries d order by d.TransactTime"`

The string `TransactTime` is entirely random. So I try to translate the string value back to date by the `TO_DATE` keyword. Something like:

`query --query="select distinct d.value FROM /deal.entries d order by TO_DATE(d.TransactTime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')"`

This is giving the error `Query is invalid due for error : <Syntax error in query:  expecting StringLiteral, found 'TransactTime'>`

What am I missing here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are querying from /deal.entries - that means you are querying (key,value) pairs, not just the value. So maybe you need to use d.value.TransactTime.

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie to OQL :) So `query --query="select DISTINCT d.value.TransactTime, d.value FROM /deal.entries d order by d.TransactTime"` is working and it just about gets what I want.